# Trino Starburst ODBC SYNTAX_ERROR : USER_ERROR (1010)

Tags: odbc, trino, starburst

Getting following error while testing connection in windows odbc 64 and 32 manager:
[Starburst][Trino] (1010) Error occurred while trying to connect: SYNTAX_ERROR : USER_ERROR : line 1:1: mismatched input '{'. Expecting: 'ALTER', 'ANALYZE', 'CALL', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'CREATE', 'DEALLOCATE', 'DELETE', 'DENY', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DROP', 'EXECUTE', 'EXPLAIN', 'GRANT', 'INSERT', 'MERGE', 'PREPARE', 'REFRESH', 'RESET', 'REVOKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'SET', 'SHOW', 'START', 'TRUNCATE', 'UPDATE', 'USE',

Steps to recreate:

1. download and install to CentOS 7 Trino from trino.io https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/trino/trino-server-rpm/377/trino-server-rpm-377.rpm
2. configure /etc/catalog/hive.properties
3. start launcher
4. download and install Starburst ODBC 64bit to windows
5. open windows ODBC manager, input trino url and port 8080 and press test connection

default trino installation from trino.io
trino server version: 377 and 352 (both have same error)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you got any solution @Edgar?

Comment: I got the same error. On Trino GUI I could see this query `{"query":"SELECT version()","preparedStatements":{}}` sent by the ODBC client. Not yet able to find a solution

Comment: I got the same error while trying to connect trino with odbc. did you find any solution?